# 'make' fails when building the rtabmap package

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was using rtabmap_ros version 0.17.6 and working on SLAM with Gazebo as shown [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot). I wanted to take a look at the map that is stored in `~/.ros/rtabmap.db` and saw that I needed the [database viewer tool](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Tools#database-viewer) for that.

So this is where I think I played around and messed things up.

I noticed that I only had a folder called 'rtabmap_ros' and no folder called 'rtabmap' and when I tried to run the following command:

```
rtabmap-databaseViewer~/.ros/rtabmap.db
```

I got the error message:

> ```
> [ERROR] (2019-07-31 21:11:51.053)  DBDriverSqlite3.cpp:398::connectDatabaseQuery() Opened database version (0.18.3) is more recent than rtabmap installed version (0.17.6). Please update rtabmap to new version!
> ```

So I tried to [install RTAB-Map standalone libraries](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros) as shown in step 2 of 'Build from source', to later update to a newer version as shown at the end of the tutorial and it failed at `make`. So I uninstalled rtabmap and rtabmap_ros and then tried the installation instructions from the beginning and still the `make` in step 2 failed.

So I thought I might have to remove all rtabmap and rtabmap_ros folders already in the VM apart from unistalling the packages and start from the beginning. However, this time step 2 fails with:

> ```
> CMake Error at rtabmap_ros/CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package):   Could not find a configuration file for package "RTABMap" that is   compatible with requested version "0.19.3".
>
>  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
>
> /usr/local/lib/rtabmap-0.18/RTABMapConfig.cmake, version: 0.18.3
> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rtabmap-0.17/RTABMapConfig.cmake, version: 0.17.6
> /usr/local/lib/rtabmap-0.18/RTABMapConfig.cmake, version: 0.18.3
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
> "/home/malar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
> "/home/malar/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log". Invoking "cmake" failed
> ```

Now I am at a loss of how to fix this issue. I still have the 'rtabmap_ros' and 'rtabmap' folders that I deleted in trash (just in case). Do I just move them back into their place?

And ever since I tried to update the 'rtabmap_ros' packages, when I run `roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch simulation:=true`. I get the following error:

```
Failed to load nodelet [/rtabmap/rtabmap] of type [rtabmap_ros/rtabmap] even after refreshing the cache: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type rtabmap_ros::CoreWrapper as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
 
The error before refreshing the cache was: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type rtabmap_ros::CoreWrapper as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

**How do I successfully update rtabmap and rtabmap_ros to be able to use the database viewer tool? If not, how do I restore everything back to how it was, so that at the very least rtabmap_ros works?**

Edit: So, I moved the 'rtabmap_ros' folders to their original positions and tried to just run `catkin_make -j1` and it worked. However, when updating the 'rtabmap_ros' package `catkin_make -j1 --pkg rtabmap_ros` fails with:

```
Packages "rtabmap_ros" not found in the workspace
```

PS: I am using ROS Kinetic in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM.

Best regards,
Malar.[C:\fakepath\Error_Frames.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1564803343619619.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329760/%27make%27-fails-when-building-the-rtabmap-package./) by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may have multiple versions of rtabmap. `rtabmap-databaseViewer` is installed with the binaries. To make it simple, remove rtabmap installed by source, then make sure you upgrade both `ros-kinetic-rtabmap` and `ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros` packages to latest version:

```
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/rtabmap*
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/rtabmap*
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/librtabmap*
$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/rtabmap*

$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros ros-kinetic-rtabmap
```

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on 2019-08-05**:
Hi Mathieu,

Thank you very much for your response. I followed your suggestion and installed rtabmap and rtabmap_ros again following this [tutorial](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros). I built rtabmap successfully, however, `catkin_make -j1` fails for rtabmap_ros with the following error:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/librtabmap_core.so', needed by '/home/malar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rtabmap_ros/pointcloud_to_depthimage'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:10766: recipe for target 'rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rtabmap_ros/CMakeFiles/rtabmap_pointcloud_to_depthimage.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1" failed
```

How would I fix this?

Best regards,
Malar.

**Comment by [MalarJN](https://answers.ros.org/users/43729/malarjn/) on 2019-08-08**:
I built it from source using [this](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros) tutorial and it worked the second time. Thank you.